# Merge query to distribute equal number of records between 100 users

Tags: oracle

I have two tables in Oracle, in first table I have 100 users and in second table I have 100000 records. I want to distribute equal amount of records between them.....

Instead of writing updating and using rownum <= 1000 to distribute data....I want to write merge statement that can divide equal number of records between 100 users.

**Table 1**

```
column A Column B  column c
  1       Pre      90008765
  2      Pre      90008766 and so on like this
```

**Table 2**

```
column a Column B column C Column d 
1         null     null    null
2          null    null    null 
And so on will have 100000 records
```

and between these two tables column a will be common in which we can apply join condition..... please guide me with merge query

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly these words *"write merge statement that can divide equal number of records between 100 users"*, you want this:

```
merge into table2 tgt
using (
select tb.rwd, ta.a 
  from (select rownum rn, a, b, c, count(1) over () cnt from table1) ta
  join (select rowid rwd, rownum rn, a, b, c, d from table2) tb
    on mod(ta.rn, cnt) = mod(tb.rn, cnt)) src
on (tgt.rowid = src.rwd)
when matched then update set a = src.a
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a7d0ee059b014b3208ef0eb6fd6982b6)</sup>**

This statement assigns rows from T1 to rows in T2 in sequence 1-2-3-...-1-2-3-..., using function `mod()`. Of course you can update other columns if you need, not only `A`.